# Which specific browser-version does compiling to Javascript form dart are supported?

Tags: dart, dart2js

I have read "Browsers and compiling to JavaScript" FAQs section https://www.dartlang.org/support/faq.html

There it says -> **We support the following browsers**:

```
•Internet Explorer, versions 9, 10, and 11. 
•Dart v1.5 was the last release to support Internet Explorer 9.
•Firefox, latest version.
•Chrome, latest version.
•Safari for desktop, version 6.
•Safari for mobile, version 6.
```

But this seems a bit outdated.

What is the `latest version` of `Firefox` or `Chrome` for this FAQ?

Since which version of FireFox does compiling to javasscript is supported?
What about `Edge` or `Opera`?

Is there a place where a I can watch info like that? I mean browsers-version supported?

Comment: @KuKeC: please don't use `inline code spans` to highlight words -- they should only be used for code/variables in sentences. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990 for more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last major version of evergreen browsers are officially supported.